# Sneding SMTP Mail with Office365 from SQL2000 DTS

Tags: email, vbscript, sql-server-2000, dts

we have migrated from a shared Exchange email host to Office 365.  We have some old SQL2000 DTS Active X scripts (vbscript) sending mail that have quit working now.  We are sending using CDO and connecting with SMTP.  I don't believe anything on the server or our network have changed, but not 100% sure.  Below is the vbscript.  We are getting a "transport failed to connect to the server" error on the .Send line.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
'**********************************************************************
```

'  Visual Basic ActiveX Script
'************************************************************************

```
Function Main()
    '# Get a preconfigured "CDO.Message" object
    Set oMail = GetCdoMessageObject()

    '# Send email
    With oMail
        .From = "mailsend@ourdomain.com"
        .To = "me@ourdomain.com"
        .Subject = "test to cfoster@ourdomain.coml"
        .TextBody = "This message was sent from a DTS package."
        .HtmlBody = "<div><p>This <i>message</i> was sent from a <b>DTS</b> package.</p></div>"
        .Send
    End With

    '# Clean Up
    Set oMail = Nothing

    '# Return
    Main = DTSTaskExecResult_Success
End Function

Function GetCdoMessageObject()
    Dim CdoMessage
    Set CdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    CdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'CdoSendUsingPort
    CdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="smtp.office365.com"
    CdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587
    CdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") =  True  'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
    CdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    CdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'cdoBasic
    CdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="mailsend@ourdomain.com"
    CdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="passwordhere"
    CdoMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

    Set GetCdoMessageObject = CdoMessage
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I specified SSL true then I had to comment out the line specifying port 587.